# Can you give examples for attachments & inlineImages in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, blob, gmail-api

[Class GmailMessage](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message) mostly accepts simple *advanced parameter* types like String and Boolean, except:

| Name | Type | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| attachments | BlobSource[] | an array of files to send with the email |
| inlineImages | Object | a JavaScript object containing a mapping from image key (String) to image data (BlobSource); this assumes that the htmlBody parameter is used and contains references to these images in the format |

Can you give examples for these two?

For example, replace the dots with example values in `var obj`:

```
// 1x1 image that can be used:
// data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAIAAACQd1PeAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAAMSURBVBhXY/j//z8ABf4C/qc1gYQAAAAASUVORK5CYII=

var obj = {attachments: [...], inlineImages: ...];
message.forward('someone@somewhere.com', obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use some like this function to insert images from my Google Photos Library:

```
function sendEmails103(obj) {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('libImages');
  const [hA, ...dt] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  let idx = {};
  hA.forEach((h, i) => idx[h] = i);
  let imgObj = {};
  vs = dt.filter(r => r[idx['filename']] == obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']])
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    let params = { muteHttpExceptions: true, headers: { "Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken() } };
    let aurl = "https://photoslibrary.googleapis.com/v1/mediaItems/" + r[idx['mediaItemId']]
    let resp = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(aurl, params).getContentText());
    let burl = `${resp.baseUrl}=w${r[idx['maxwidth']]}-h${r[idx['maxheight']]}`
    imgObj[r[idx['Key']]] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(burl).getBlob();
  });
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']]);
  let html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  if (html) {
    if (obj.row[obj.index['operation']] == 'Create Draft') {
      GmailApp.createDraft(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    } else {
      GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']],obj.row[obj.index['Subject']],'',{htmlBody:html,inlineImages:imgObj,replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']]});
    }
  }
}
```

I keep the mediaItemIds and keys in a spreadsheet like this:

| Key | Description | mediaItemId | maxwidth | maxheight | filename |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| img0 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img1 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img2 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img3 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img4 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img5 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img6 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |
| img7 | Redacted | Redacted | 384 | 384 | file103 |

This is a simpler example that uses images from my Drive:

```
function sendEmails101(obj) {
  let imgObj = {};
  let fldr = DriveApp.getFolderById("folderid");
  let files = fldr.getFilesByType(MimeType.JPEG);
  let n = 0;
  let names = ['die1.jpg', 'die2.jpg'];
  let filename = [];
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    let f = files.next();
    let index = names.indexOf(f.getName());
    if (~index) {
      imgObj[`img${n++}`] = f.getBlob();
      filename.push(names[index]);
    }
  }
  let htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile(obj.row[obj.index['htmlFile']]);
  htmlTemplate.values = obj.row.slice(obj.index['Data0']);
  htmlTemplate.filename = filename;
  let html = htmlTemplate.evaluate().getContent();
  if (html) {
    if (obj.row[obj.index[operation]] == 'Create Draft') {
      GmailApp.createDraft(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    } else {

      GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.row[obj.index['Recipients']], obj.row[obj.index['Subject']], '', { htmlBody: html, inlineImages: imgObj, replyTo: obj.row[obj.index['replyTo']] });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That's a nice example for `inlineImages`, do you also have one for `attachments`? I've tested it, so if you want, just edit your answer and add `{attachments: UrlFetchApp.fetch(burl).getBlob()}` - it works. Then I'll accept.

Comment: Can you please add to the answer so I'll accept?